# Why is dropdown menu not working?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I work for this company that wants to display categories of posts as dropdown menu. It all works on chrome from my part, but one of my fellow colleagues said it didn't work on her computer, she uses Chrome as well but not on Pc but Mac.

I then checked the pages on IE and Firefox and it doesn't work there for me. It just shows bullet list of the items.

I've already tried clearing cache/cookies, check the doctype (should be fine) and tried changing the selector for the hover element. These things did not work!

I would like to ask if you also get a bullet list or a hoverable dropdown menu? And which browser are you using?

Here's the link:
www.vibro.no/mag/

And here's the code:

CSS:

```
#menu-item-2022 {
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

ul > li {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.sub-menu a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {background-color: black;}

#menu-item-2022:hover .sub-menu {
display: block;
}

#menu-item-2022:hover #menu-item-2022 {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

HTML:
    [KATEGORIER](http://www.vibro.no/kategorier/)

```
<li id="menu-item-2098" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2098 first-child"><a href="http://www.vibro.no/category/kategori-3/">WHATS UP SOCIETY?</a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-2097" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2097"><a href="http://www.vibro.no/category/kategori-2/">SPOTLIGHT</a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-2096" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2096"><a href="http://www.vibro.no/category/kategori-1/">UP &amp; COMING</a>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2099 last-child"><a href="http://www.vibro.no/category/video/">VIDEO</a>
</li>

</ul>`
```

Comment: are you using any libraries like bootstrap,jquery

Comment: from your code , menu-item-2022 is missing

Comment: No, I don't think so. How can I check that?

Comment: Sorry, was just me not posting the full html code.

Comment: I think your code is not implemented yet. Check out the sub-menu class. Your codes are not there !

Comment: Here's the rest,

Comment: <li id="menu-item-2022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2022 first-child"><a href="http://www.vibro.no/kategorier/">KATEGORIER</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
</ul>

Comment: PS! sub-menu element wraps around the li's. I've read something about that :hover don't work in firefox or IE. Therefore I looked at the doctype but it was like I was recommended to. Any ideas?

Comment: My friend, once again. The CSS codes that you have provided for us here is not in the link that you have posted. There is maybe something wrong with uploading them.

Comment: What excactly can't you find?

Comment: Check out .sub-menu with chrome developer tools. The CSS codes that you pasted here is not there. These are what I'm talking about:
`.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}`

Comment: Ok. Now the dropdown menu doesn't work in chrome either. What do you see? I use FileZilla to upload my files and I thought it worked until my colleague said the dropdown menu on her computer didn't work.

Comment: I'm seeing your drop-down with chrome: WHATS UP SOCIETY?
SPOTLIGHT
UP & COMING
VIDEO

Comment: Did you got the point?

Comment: @AlexanderMyrvold , i have codepen with provided code - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xWQOKM, check if you are looking for something like this

Comment: Ok, I can't find the codes either. When I open the style.css file I can find all my code. So the problem is that the browsers can't read some of my code.

Comment: it seems sub menu and hover css are missing

Comment: Naga Sai: I want dropdown menu when I hover "kategorier" with the items you've listed. Soheil: I see what you mean. But the question is how can I make the css code usable to the browser? PS! Now it doesn't work on any of the following browsers (IE, Firefox and chrome), but only on computer, on mobile it works fine. Weird...

Comment: do you see console errors ? how are you loading css files ?

Comment: You may have a syntax error some where in your style sheet. Browsers will omit the rest of the code in this case because they can not read the wrong syntax. Copy and paste your code in a good IDE to discover where it is ...

Comment: I don't see any errors. We load the files by linking to them. The problem isn't that the whole file is missing, only the hover and sub-menu styles

Comment: But what explains that it worked fine in Chrome for me but not for my colleague, and now doesn't work in Chrome for me. The css is the same as before!

Comment: is this the actual css with other css parameters - http://www.vibro.no/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/9917c21870f3e86caa5f8f8658fe9fdf/1521656818index.css

Comment: Strange. It looks like it but I see font-family is different than what I have on my css file. Where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

this might help

**JS CODE**

```
if($( ".nav-bar li" ).hasClass( ".sub-menu" )){
// if you want to use font-awesome or anything else. 
$('.nav-bar li::before').append('<span class="toggle-caret"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>');
$('.nav-bar li .sub-menu').hide();
$(".nav-bar li").on('hover', function(){

    $('.nav-bar li .sub-menu').show();

});
};
```

**CSS**

```
nav.nav-bar li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Haven't tested it tho.

Comment: in a custom.js (file if you a dev,) or through the wp customizer, most themes have options to allow JS code .. please xtell me if this works out for you.

Comment: It didn't work. Found a js file in ftp and added the code, then added the css, but no changes.